Reading telegram messages using Python
I have wrote the following code which ideally is able to execute and "listen" to new messages coming in the specified chat ID.
I noticed it wasn't doing anything, despite new messages showing up in the chat ID. Would someone know what is missing for it to work? I have double checked the bot token from BotFather (that due to security reasons I blanked it).
Been exploring for a while until having decided to post here for some help. For additional context, my goal is that whenever there is a new message, it prints the text and also saves it into a json file.
import json
import asyncio
import time
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.error import TelegramError
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

om_private_alerts_channel_id = '' 
bot_token = 'sample:sample' # from BotFather

# Function to process messages
def process_message(message):
    text = message.text
    entities = message.entities
    # Print message details to console
    print(text)
    print(entities)
    # Save message details to log.json
    log_entry = {
        "text": text,
        "entities": entities
    }
    with open('log.json', 'a') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(log_entry) + '\n')

# Async function to receive messages
async def receive_messages(bot):
    last_update_id = None
    while True:
        try:
            updates = await bot.get_updates(
                offset=last_update_id, timeout=30, allowed_updates=[])
            if updates:
                last_update_id = updates[-1].update_id + 1
                for update in updates:
                    message = update.channel_post
                    if message:
                        if str(message.chat.id) == om_private_alerts_channel_id:
                            process_message(message)
        except TelegramError as e:
            print("Error receiving messages:", e)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

# Main async function
async def main():
    bot = Bot(bot_token)

    try:
        # Start receiving messages asynchronously
        await receive_messages(bot)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Bot stopped.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


Channel IDs are negative, can you ensure the om_private_alerts_channel_id is negative, i.e., starts with a -.
Ref.
